# How to create the media controller for playing audio?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have done code for playing audio by using the media controller. My code is working properly but some exceptions occurs while running the code.

```
  public class CallHistoryActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{

    Button audioPlayer;

    private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";

    public static final String AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "audioFileName";

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaController mediaController;
    private String audioFile;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_history);
        audioPlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.audioPlayer);

    }

    public void audioplayer(View view)
    {

        String path =new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NewCallLogs/Yaendi Yaendi.mp3 ");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaController = new MediaController(this);


        mediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(uri));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


public void stopPlayer(View view)
{
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
        mediaController.show();
        return false;
    }

    //--MediaPlayerControl methods----------------------------------------------------
    public void start() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return 0;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        mediaPlayer.start();

        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer((MediaController.MediaPlayerControl) this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                mediaController.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The exception shown in the logcat is shown below

```
    02-20 14:56:42.402 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
02-20 14:56:42.412 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
02-20 14:56:42.412 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-20 14:56:42.422 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-20 14:56:42.422 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
02-20 14:56:42.422 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
02-20 14:56:45.442 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
02-20 14:56:53.402 21410-21421/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
02-20 14:56:56.072 21410-21421/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
02-20 14:56:57.602 21410-21421/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
02-20 14:56:58.792 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
02-20 14:56:58.792 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

Then the layout design for the media controller is shown below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_audio_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.seyali.newcalllogs.CallHistoryActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/audioPlayer"
    android:onClick="audioplayer"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/stopPlaying"
    android:onClick="stopPlayer"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Now playing:"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/now_playing_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Now playing.."
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

Please help me how to overcome this exception.I tried all the methods but my problem was not solved.Please help me.

Comment: See this..... https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/

Comment: Ok, i will try this.

Comment: Please help me how to solve that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayer should follow a design.
Please see : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

mediaplayer.stop() should trigger from  play state(after calling start).

02-20 14:56:58.792 21410-21410/com.sey.newcalllogs E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0

```
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(uri));
mediaPlayer.prepare();

   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

only after all these step you can call mediaPlayer.stop();

The above error showing your calling stop from wrong state.Please check

Comment: How to mediaplayer.stop() should be triggered from play state().@Ranjith KP

Comment: I don't know how to implement the answer what you posted.

Comment: see the flow diagram in that link.

Comment: i have know idea i reffered the the diagram ,i think my code is correct

Comment: In your code your not  declaring mediaplayer object as global.

Comment: you  are  creating mediaplayer object locally  from  the method public void audioplayer(View view) and you are  trying to call mediaplayer.stop from another method public void stopPlayer(View view).May be this will be the issue.

Comment: I declared the media player as global but still exception is not cleared

Comment: which execption is showing now ' Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'' or "E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0" ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue check the state of the mediaPlayer before calling the methods. For example:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
mediaPlayer.pause();
```

}

Please let me know it fixes the problem or not

Comment: No, problem is not fixed.

Comment: Have you done like this? please confirm
public void stopPlayer(View view)
{
   if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
}